# JSF Portlets in Liferay on JBoss

Tags: jboss, application-server, cms

I'm currently looking at working with and deploying JSF portlets into Liferay 6.0.5, sitting on JBoss 5.1.0. I ran into a lot of trouble trying to port some JSF-y/Seam-y/EJB-y stuff I had lying around, so I thought I'd start simple and work my way up.

I could generate generic portlets using the NetBeans Maven archetype for Liferay portlets absolutely fine, but it's rather irrelevant because I wanted JSF portlets

I took an example JSF portlet from http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/community-plugins/-/software_catalog/products/5546866 and attempted to deploy into a clean, vanilla installation of Liferay 6.0.5/JBoss 5.1.0 to no avail. The log messages are reproduced at the end of this.

This particular example was actually tested for GlassFish and Tomcat, so it's not particularly helpful considering I'm deplying into JBoss. I tried ripping it apart and removing the jsf implementation contained within as there is a jsf implementation shipped with JBoss (Mojarra 1.2_12, in this case).

> 03:16:17,173 INFO  [PortletAutoDeployListener] Copying portlets for /usr/local/[REDACTED]/liferay/liferay-portal-6.0.5/deploy/richfaces-sun-jsf1.2-facelets-portlet-1.2.war
>     Expanding: /usr/local/[REDACTED]/liferay/liferay-portal-6.0.5/deploy/richfaces-sun-jsf1.2-facelets-portlet-1.2.war into /tmp/20110201031617188
>     Copying 1 file to /tmp/20110201031617188/WEB-INF
>     Copying 1 file to /tmp/20110201031617188/WEB-INF/classes
>     Copying 1 file to /tmp/20110201031617188/WEB-INF/classes
>     Copying 47 files to /usr/local/[REDACTED]/liferay/liferay-portal-6.0.5/jboss-5.1.0/server/default/deploy/richfaces-sun-jsf1.2-facelets-portlet.war
>     Copying 1 file to /usr/local/[REDACTED]/liferay/liferay-portal-6.0.5/jboss-5.1.0/server/default/deploy/richfaces-sun-jsf1.2-facelets-portlet.war
>     Deleting directory /tmp/20110201031617188
>   03:16:20,075 INFO  [PortletAutoDeployListener] Portlets for /usr/local/[REDACTED]/liferay/liferay-portal-6.0.5/deploy/richfaces-sun-jsf1.2-facelets-portlet-1.2.war copied successfully. Deployment will start in a few seconds.
>   03:16:23,632 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/richfaces-sun-jsf1.2-facelets-portlet
>   03:16:24,446 INFO  [PortletHotDeployListener] Registering portlets for richfaces-sun-jsf1.2-facelets-portlet
>   03:16:24,492 INFO  [faces] Init GenericFacesPortlet for portlet 1
>   03:16:24,495 INFO  [faces] Bridge class name is org.jboss.portletbridge.AjaxPortletBridge
>   03:16:24,509 INFO  [faces] The bridge does not support doHeaders method
>   03:16:24,510 INFO  [faces] GenericFacesPortlet for portlet 1 initialized
>   03:16:24,555 INFO  [PortletHotDeployListener] 1 portlet for richfaces-sun-jsf1.2-facelets-portlet is available for use
>   03:16:24,627 SEVERE [webapp] Initialization of the JSF runtime either failed or did not occurr.  Review the server''s log for details. 
>   java.lang.InstantiationException: org.jboss.portletbridge.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>           at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:537)
>           at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:394)
>           at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:135)
>           at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:717)
>           at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:239)
>           at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:164)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:950)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4122)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4421)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
>           at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
>           at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
>           at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor286.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
>           at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>           at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
>           at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
>           at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
>           at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
>           at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   03:16:24,629 INFO  [2-facelets-portlet]] Marking servlet FacesServlet as unavailable
>   03:16:24,630 ERROR [2-facelets-portlet]] Servlet /richfaces-sun-jsf1.2-facelets-portlet threw load() exception
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization of the JSF runtime either failed or did not occurr.  Review the server''s log for details. 
>           at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:172)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:950)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4122)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4421)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
>           at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
>           at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
>           at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor286.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
>           at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>           at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
>           at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
>           at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
>           at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
>           at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular problem arose because the JBoss that comes bundled with Liferay is severely cut down, but also includes some other things you wouldn't find in a vanilla Jboss 5.1.0 instance.

In this case, there was a problem with the versions of the Portlet Bridge. I was packaging one, and there was one provided by Liferay's Jboss.

I presume that sorting this out would have fixed it, but I've decided that the JSF lifecycle and the Portlet lifecycle really don't mesh well together, so it's time to look at other types of Portlets for me.